# Hyper-V not starting Windows 8.1 formally had VirtualBox installed

Tags: hyper-v, virtualbox, windows-8.1

I'm a Windows developer and I want to get started with Windows Phone 8. I previously had Oracle VirtualBox installed but was told that the Windows Phone Emulator needs Hyper-V, which doesn't work well with VirtualBox.

This wasn't an issue, so I uninstalled VirtualBox and added the Hyper-V feature (I'm using Windows 8.1).

I now cannot start the Hyper-V management service, I get the error below when I try and start through services.msc:

[image]

Couple of additional bits of information...

I uninstalled Hyper-V when I first got the laptop, as I wanted to use VirtualBox. VirtualBox was running fine so I don't think there is anything wrong with my laptop hardware.

I also went into my BIOS, disabled Virtualization and then removed the battery for a couple of minutes (on the advise of a tech guy) and then re-enabled it and re-booted but I still get the same error.

Laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L850, link below:

[Toshiba Laptop](http://www.mytoshiba.com.au/products/computers/satellite/l850/pskfwa-01r012/specifications)

Can anyone suggest anything to try? At the minute, all I can think is to perform a clean re-install of Windows.

Comment: Yep, added back in that I renabled it again.

Comment: And what does the event log say?

Comment: The same as the screenshot that I added: The Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service terminated with the following error: 
Invalid pointer

Comment: Any suggestions?